# How to refresh Firebase IdToken after it expires?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I'm using express as my backend and I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK to send back the token to the client.
At the moment the token is expired after 1 Hour.  I read on the firebase that there isn't any way to change the expiration property because the way it works - the user will get a refreshed token every hour. Is that correct? If so, how I supposed to implement it? 
Here is my login route:

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  }
  // Validate Data
  const { valid, errors } = validateLogin(user)
  if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors)

  try {
    const data = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    const token = await data.user.getIdToken()
    const cookieOptions = {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
    }
    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions)
    return res.status(201).json({ token })
  } catch (err) {
    errors.general = 'Wrong credentials, please try again'
    return res.status(403).json(errors)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do on the backend to implement token refreshing.  The client app will do that automatically using the Firebase Auth SDK.

Anyway, backend apps aren't supposed to sign in the user - that won't work out the way you expect.  When using Firebase Auth, client apps are supposed to [sign in using the client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start).  The client app signs in, gets a token, then passes that token to the backend to be [verified](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) using the Firebase Admin SDK, then acted on.

Comment: I followed a course and over there we implemented the login in a different ways. 
The email and password were sent to the server and then we generated a token by verifying the email and the password using the admin SDK

Comment: Well, that's not the way Firebase is intended to work. Maybe other systems work that way. The sign-in is expected to come from the client, and tokens passed to the server.  Please read the documentation links I provided for more information.

Comment: I am familiar with the documentation. However, Firebase does have Admin SDK which allows doing the auth through the backend. I guess they add it for a reason =)

Comment: Yes, in this case, it's used for verifying the token that you send from the client. There is a link to that in my answer.  The Admin SDK is not used for signing in users.

Comment: @DougStevenson it's not clear in the documentation what exactly will trigger a token to be refreshed. By default if I'm correct it's a one hour token. It's possible to force a refresh on the client sdk when the user sign in. After that found no way to refresh the token so the user does not have to enter his password again in order to stay logged in. Is it automatically refreshed when the user interact with the app or is it anything we need to do in order to avoid the user to authenticate every time the token expires?